# How can we check analytics code of my site?

Tags: google-analytics

I am working on a site Local.mensusa.com. which is sob domain of www.mensusa.com.

I added a analytics code to my site but unable to get traffic on my site.

My code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
  ga('create', 'UA-2085156-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

1: Is this the right code?

2: There is same code pattern for domain and sub domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes your code looks correct.  If you want to be able to compare the data between the Doman and the subdomain then you should use the same tracking code.   If you want to keep the data separate ex: two sites that have no relation to each other what so ever, than create a separate account for it.

Possible causes of your problem are.

1. When did you create the analytics account? it can take 48 - 72 hours for new accounts to begin recording data.
2. How long ago did you add that code to your site? it can take 24 - 48 hours for new code to start recording data.
3. Did you check the Real-time report? Standard reports take 24 hours to complete processing.

This tool is also useful for checking that your code is correct.  [Extension Google Analytics Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

It should be the right code. Otherwise, copy/paste it from the dashboard again.

In order to test it, you can easily check if you currently have visitors on your website: go to real time section.

Finally, about subdomain, you have to create another website to watch (with another google code) to track data.